# How can I add a "x" button in a jQuery toggle function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am new with jQuery and there are a few things I want to add to my code.

What I more or less want (found it online): http://jsfiddle.net/EMYFt/5/

I have a loop in PHP creating all of those DIVs(at their x,y coordinate) and thats why I need to add a button. I want every desk_box DIV when click to remain open until the user decides to click X. Right now I got it working only if the user clicks on the same DIV. It is annoying because eventually it hides the other ones and I have to refresh the page. So, adding the (x) button would help.

Thanks in advance it is appreciated!

Below is my code ([JSFiddle mirror](http://jsfiddle.net/ongv8h9e/)):

I want to add an (x) button in in my station_info_ DIV which is being toggled.Also, how can I make that DIV overlay on top of the desk_box DIV (look at my fiddle: when you click on 84 it will go under 100.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".desk_box").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data")
    $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#map_size{
  position:center;
  width:1190px;
  height:1300px;
  background:#0099FF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box{ 
  width: 23px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black; 
  padding:10px;
} 

/*station info*/ 
.station_info_ {
  display: none;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:20px;
  border:4px solid black;
  background-color:white;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_size">
  <div class="desk_box" data="84" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:80px;">id:84</div>

  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_84" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <p>Hello the id is:84</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>

  <div class="desk_box" data="90" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:120px;">id:90</div>

  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_90" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <p>Hello the id is:90</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desk_box" data="100" style="position:absolute;left:120px;top:120px;">id:100</div>
  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_100" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <p>Hello the id is:100</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something about this X functionnality ? because i don't see in your code anything that could make this work. Plus it's like the 4th time you post problem about this "projet" in few day...

Comment: theres 4 possible answers already given below that work because of good people in this website that are willing to help people like me who are learning a new language. If you say that you saw this same problem "4 times" (which isn't the same exact questions) then why not help?

Comment: I was asking you if you tried anything about the problem / search. I never said people shouldn't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question about going under, you need to set the z-index

```
.station_info_ { 
    z-index:10;
    ....
```

and to add an X

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".desk_box").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data")
      var st = $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();
       if (!st.has(".close").length) {
            st.prepend('<button class="close">X</button>');
       }
   });//end click
});//end ready

$(document).on("click",".close", function () {
   $(this).parent().toggle(); 
});
```

```css
#map_size{
 position:center;
 width:1190px;
 height:1300px;
 background:#0099FF;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 position: relative;
 }
/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box{ 
 width: 23px;
 height: 10px;
 border: 4px solid black; 
 padding:10px;
} 

/*station info*/ 
.station_info_ {
    display: none;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border:4px solid black;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

button.close {
    position: absolute; top:0px; right:0px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_size">
<div class="desk_box" data="84" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:80px;">id:84</div>

<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_84" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;"><p>Hello the id is:84</p><p>Section: H</p></div>

<div class="desk_box" data="90" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:120px;">id:90</div>

<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_90" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;"><p>Hello the id is:90</p><p>Section: H</p></div>

<div class="desk_box" data="100" style="position:absolute;left:120px;top:120px;">id:100</div>

<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_100" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;"><p>Hello the id is:100</p><p>Section: H</p></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: awesome works perfect thanks for the help! I combined yours with the other answers since their all good!

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled with a closing (X) button
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".desk_box").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data")
    $("#station_info_" + id).toggle();
  }); //end click

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $("#station_info_" + $(this).data("id")).hide();
  });
}); //end ready
```

```css
#map_size {
  position: center;
  width: 1190px;
  height: 1300px;
  background: #0099FF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
/* desk boxes*/

.desk_box {
  width: 23px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*station info*/

.station_info_ {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_size">
  <div class="desk_box" data="84" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:80px;">id:84</div>

  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_84" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <span data-id="84" class="close" style="float:right;">x</span>
    <p>Hello the id is:84</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>

  <div class="desk_box" data="90" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:120px;">id:90</div>

  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_90" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <span data-id="90" class="close" style="float:right;">x</span>
    <p>Hello the id is:90</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>

  <div class="desk_box" data="100" style="position:absolute;left:120px;top:120px;">id:100</div>

  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_100" style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:90px;">
    <span data-id="100" class="close" style="float:right;">x</span>
    <p>Hello the id is:100</p>
    <p>Section: H</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a closing button or span to `station_info_` class like

```
<span class="close">x</span>
```

Add a listener to it to close the box like:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggle();
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ongv8h9e/4/)

I also added some css to the closing X

CSS:

```
.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;    
}

.close:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Finally change the `z-index` of the station_info_ class like:

```
.station_info_ {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:20px;
    border:4px solid black;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: awesome works perfect thanks for the help! I combined yours with the other answers since  their all good!

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto steve Webb's code, I also addressed the z-index issue, and made sure that we only hide when clicking on the x by changing "toggle" to "show"

http://jsfiddle.net/ongv8h9e/8/

```
//Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled with a closing (X) button
$(document).ready(function() {
  var zmax=1;
  $(".desk_box").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data");
    $("#station_info_"+id).show().css("z-index",zmax++);
   });//end click

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggle();
  });
});//end ready
```